# The right way to authenticate user on Symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with Symfony authentication. I've read many manuals, but with no result. I want to understand how can I correctly render the login form using `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig` for the errors displaying. Cause when I'm trying to login it shows ugly message `invalid credentials`.
So, my `UserLoginType` is :

```
class UserLoginType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array 
$options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class,
                ['constraints' => array(new Length(array('min' => 3)))])
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

My `security.yaml` file exactly like in documentation:
[image]

Of course with additional fields names (cause I'm using symfony forms for the rendering),
Here my test login method:

```
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserLoginType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump($form->getData());
        die();
    }
    return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView(),
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'        => $error,
        ]);
}
```

And here my `login.html.twig`:

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login page{% endblock %}

{% block description %}This is login page{% endblock %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, when I'm trying to login:
[image]

How can I get something like this:
[image]

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your approach.  In particular, you need _username and _password form elements or you need to tweak your configuration.  Plenty of other things wrong as well.  I would suggest creating a new project then work you way through the security docs step by step just to see how everything fits together.  Then customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the "invalid credential" message because Symfony handles the authentication, you dont need to process the form yourself. From the docs:

*Don't let this controller confuse you. As you'll see in a moment, when the user submits the form, the security system automatically handles the form submission for you. If the user submits an invalid username or password, this controller reads the form submission error from the security system, so that it can be displayed back to the user.*

Why would you give an error like "username should be 3 characters or longer" on a login form ? I Don't think these error message are needed for a login form.

Nevertheless you might be able to validate the request yourself with:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($user);
```

And then pass the errors to your view or set the errors in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of frameworks, especially awesome ones like Symfony, is that they do a lot of 'magic' for you. Need to login? Point the post form endpoint with fields to e.g /login/check. Need to validate a form? Just add a constraint? So much beauty. This beauty can also become a problem when trying to wrap your head around what's going wrong. There are many many ways to authenticate a user. I almost always prefer going manual. Like so :-

```
// To-DO, get Username and Password from request
if (!$username || !$password) {
  throw error;
}

// Query DB for user example using.
$user = $em->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

if (!$user) {
  throw 404 error;
}

// The juice of it

// Let get the password encoder and encode the submitted password to see if it matches
$encoder_service = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $encoder_service->getEncoder($user);

if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $user->getSalt())) {
  throw bad password exception;
}

// We're good to go, the user with the name and password was found in the DB so let's log him/her in

// Get the security firewall name, and login the user
$providerKey = 'firewall_name'; // e.g main
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $password, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

// Fire the login event to notify any listeners
$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

// Continue your logic
```

As I said, many ways to skin this particular cat, so pick your poison.